# Where can I find script that convert VC++ inline assembler to intrinsics?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly, intrinsics

I am porting inline assembler that use SSE commands to intrinsics. It takes much work to find appropriate intrinsic for assembler instruction. Somewhere on the Internet I saw a Python script that simplifies the job, but cannot find it now.

Comment: Why don't you use an assembler?  You already got ml64.exe, vc/bin/x86_amd64 subdirectory.

Comment: @Hans Passant, because not simple extract inline assembler to separate assembler and then support separate x86 and x64 assembler code

Comment: A lot simpler than what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created my own script to convert inline assembler to intrinsics. He does a lot of rough work.
https://github.com/KindDragon/Asm2Intrinsics

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be happy with such a script.

First, in my opinion intrinsics are only useful for a one or two liner, if you have more instructions it is possible better to have a separate assembler file. Also with a long listing of assembler instructions you will have to control the result anyway, which include to understand each instruction and its result, which basically means you can write it again in the same time.

Second, I think you are looking for something like this because you want to port a piece of software from 32 bit to 64 bit, right? My experience told me that you will run into some strange errors because of some unexpected type casts if you don't have a look on every line of code.

Third, are you talking about Visual Studio? Is there any other compiler which supports intrinsics? We had some strange errors while porting our software using intrinsics, because there are some ugly compiler bugs while using intrinsics, mostly by messing up the stack. We had a lot of trouble in finding these things and ending up to write these functions in assembler.

So my suggestion is to be careful with intrinsics!

Comment: Yes. I'm porting a lot of 32bit inline assembler code to 64bit. I just want simplify my work, rather than solve it completely. 
VC++, GCC, Intel CC and Clang support SSE intrinsics.

Comment: @Confused: That's not at all true. Intrinsics are superior to assembler for all uses- they're much more portable and more optimizable.

Comment: Visual Studio has indeed had a bad history of miscompiling intrinsics. However, these bugs are so big and obvious that they always get fixed in a followup release or patch. As of VS2010 SP1, I'm unaware of bugs in the intrinsics. But VS2010 completely miscompiled all the AVX permute instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a script that will do exactly what you asking. A lot of cases will also have non-SSE instructions interleaved into the assembly, and not every assembly instruction can be mapped to an intrinsic or a primitive C operation.

I suppose you can probably hack you way through it with find-and-replace. (This actually might not be that bad. How much code are you trying port? Thousands of lines?)

Also, VC++ doesn't allow inline assembly at all on 64-bit. So everything needs to be done using intrinsics or a completely separate assembly file.

I won't go far to say that using intrinsics is completely inferior to assembly (assuming you know what you're doing), but writing good intrinsic code that compiles well and runs as fast as optimized assembly is a work of art on it's own. But it maintains two advantages: portability, and ease of use (no need to manually allocate registers).